# Convert DateTime to ISO 8601

Tags: datetime, dart

In Dart, how can I convert a [DateTime](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-core.DateTime) to its [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm) representation?

Just doing this

```
var dt = new DateTime.now();
print (dt.toString());
```

produces

```
2014-02-15 08:57:47.812
```

which isn't quite ISO 8601, that would be

```
2014-02-15T08:57:47.812
```

so only the "T" is missing - I can easily write my own function for this, just wondering if that already exists somewhere in the core libraries?

The other direction, ISO 8601 to DateTime, is already supported by [DateTime.parse](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-core.DateTime@id_parse).

**EDIT** looks like the Dart team is adding this now, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16902).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

use :

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String isoDate = now.toIso8601String();
```

Answer (score 8):

DateTime now has a `toIso8601String()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The core library doesn't support a toIso8601() on DateTime, yet. It's relatively easy to do yourself, but I agree that Iso8601 and Rfc-2311 should probably be supported as special toStrings.

Similarly the parse function should accept Rfc-2311, too.